# Yii2 Redirect with OpenShift Proxy

Tags: php, nginx, yii2, openshift

I have deployed a `Yii2` based `PHP` application on `OpenShift`. Basically, `Yii2` is running in a container based on `alpine` with `PHP` and `Nginx` installed. The container exposes `port 8080`, which is then tied to an `OpenShift` service, where in turn a secured route with `Edge encryption` is created.

Most of the application works fine, however when doing a `HTTP` post and later in the controller doing a redirect, `Yii2` redirects to `http://<sitename>` instead of staying with `https`, which leads to the application not being working anymore. The `POST` request itself works, as the changes are done to the DB afterwards, its the redirect back to overview that is not working in this context.

The controller action is very simple and standard:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Some information about the OpenShift configuration:

```
~ oc get routes 
NAME       HOST/PORT                PATH   SERVICES  PORT     TERMINATION   WILDCARD
backend    backend.apps.<instance>         backend   backend  edge          None
frontend   frontend.apps.<instance>        frontend  frontend edge          None

~ oc describe route backend
Name:           backend
Namespace:      <project>
Created:        10 hours ago
Annotations:        openshift.io/host.generated=true
Requested Host:     backend.apps.<instance> 
                    exposed on router router 10 hours ago
Path:           <none>
TLS Termination:    edge
Insecure Policy:    <none>
Endpoint Port:      backend

Service:    backend
Weight:     100 (100%)
Endpoints:  <ip>:8080
```

The Dockerfile to create the application is not very spectacular, it basically installs `PHP`, `Nginx` and sets some permissions. The `Nginx` configuration could actually be part of the problem though, posting a sanitised version below.

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log stderr warn;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main_timed  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                            '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe $upstream_cache_status';

    access_log /dev/stdout main_timed;
    error_log /dev/stderr notice;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name _;

        sendfile off;

        root /var/www/html/backend/web/;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to index.php
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/lib/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            expires 5d;
        }

        # deny access to . files, for security
        #
        location ~ /\. {
            log_not_found off;
            deny all;
        }

        # allow fpm ping and status from localhost
        #
        location ~ ^/(fpm-status|fpm-ping)$ {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

Adding the following line to the Nginx configuration somehow makes it work, however its not a nice solution:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    [...]
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

This assumes however, that always HTTPs is used. It however depends on the configuration of the OpenShift route. Is there a better (more universal) solution to it?

Comment: Your application needs to honour the `X-Proxy-Scheme` header set by `haproxy` used for routing. The value will tell you whether the original request used `http` or `https`. You should use that in any URLs your application constructs.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks for your comment! My main question is then where the header is set (probably by the OpenShift proxy/lb)? How to I tell Nginx to forward this header using fastcgi?

Comment: @waza-ari you can try the following `fastcgi_pass_header X-Proxy-Scheme;` https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass_header or `fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;` https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass_request_headers

Comment: @Aleksandar if I understand the manual correctly, `fastcgi_pass_request_headers` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all comments and answers, I was able to figure it out. I'm not using Nginx as proxy here, but I'm using FastCGI for PHP, that's why I'm not sure if the answer proposed by Jason would work. The following solutions works for me:

```
location ~ \.php$ {

    set $my_https 'off';
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'https') {
        set $my_https 'on';
    }

    fastcgi_param HTTPS $my_https;
```

There may be a more elegant solution to this, but this one is working for  me

Answer (score 1):

The OpenShift router (which is what exposes the secured route you created) will set a number of [headers](https://github.com/openshift/router/blob/master/images/router/haproxy/conf/haproxy-config.template#L427) on the request to the backend pod running your Yii2 application.

The first thing we have to do is trust these headers at Nginx so that it will relay them to the backend Yii2 application.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass_header   X-Forwarded-Proto;
    proxy_pass_header   X-Forwarded-Host;
    proxy_pass_header   X-Forwarded-Port;
    [...]
```

`X-Forwarded-Proto` will be set to `https` and it looks like [Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests#trusted-proxies) will handle the header correctly but I have not used that PHP framework before. This would be the second step if it is required which would be to have the framework craft response url's with the protocol that is in the x-forwarded-proto header.

It should be noted here that trusting these headers at the Nginx level can be dangerous if untrusted users can access Nginx directly. In this scenario they would be able to spoof requests and set these headers to be whatever they want.